# Can't connect my windows local machine to local Virtual Box debian VM

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, virtualbox

I am trying to connect Visual studio code on my local windows to virtual machine on virtualBox
via SSH,
I started by creating a VM and i did the ipconfig to get the ip address
i already installed ssh openssh server and client

In my windows i enterred this command to create ssh keys
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -f %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/linux_rsa
and when i try to copy the key to the virtual machine

scp %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/linux_rsa.pub debian@10.0.2.15:~/key.pub
scp %USERPROFILE%/.ssh/linux_rsa.pub debian@127.0.0.1:~/key.pub
(ifconfig ==> the ip adress is 10.0.2.15 ans 127.0.0.1 and don't which one is the good one)
it tells me CONNEXION refused

Answer (score 1):

First step for me would be to connect with user and password.

Just try to connect to your VM from windows with ssh 10.0.2.15. If it asks for a password, the network connection ist ok.

It could also be, that your vm is not "visible" from outside. So, check you vm settings.